# Is there a way to convert Class<? extends Something> to Class<?>

Tags: java, class, bukkit

I am currently working on a plugin, where I want to offer the possibility to create addons for.
Therefore i use a ClassLoader, which checks the folder of my plugin for JarFiles and search in them for a class extending my abstract class.

Now my ClassLoader is giving me back a list with `Class<? extends MyClass>`, but I need them to be `Class<?>` to execute the methods of this class.

I've already tried to cast it to an Object or to the class itsself, which gives me an ClassCastException.

Is there a way to convert `Class<? extends MyClass>` to `Class<?>` or a workaround way?

ClassLoader:

```
public class SPClassLoader {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<Class<? extends T>> findClasses(
        @NonNull final ClassLoader classLoader,
        @NonNull final File file,
        @NonNull final Class<T> clazz,
        @NonNull final Predicate<Class<T>> predicate
) {

    return findClasses(classLoader, file, clazz).stream()
            .filter(aClass -> predicate.test((Class<T>) aClass))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<Class<? extends T>> findClasses(
        @NonNull final ClassLoader classLoader,
        @NonNull final File file,
        @NonNull final Class<T> clazz
) {

    return findClasses(classLoader, file, clazz::isAssignableFrom).stream()
            .map(aClass -> (Class<T>) aClass.asSubclass(clazz))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public List<Class<?>> findClasses(
        @NonNull final ClassLoader classLoader,
        @NonNull final File file,
        @NonNull final Predicate<Class<?>> predicate
) {

    if (!file.exists()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        return findClassesInSourceRoot(classLoader, file, predicate);
    } else if (!file.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        final URL jar = file.toURI().toURL();

        final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

        try (final JarInputStream stream = new JarInputStream(
                jar.openStream()); final URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jar},
                classLoader)
        ) {
            JarEntry entry;
            while ((entry = stream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
                final String name = entry.getName();
                if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || !name.endsWith(".class")) {
                    continue;
                }

                matches.add(name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')).replace('/', '.'));
            }

            for (final String match : matches) {
                try {
                    final Class<?> loaded = loader.loadClass(match);
                    if (predicate.test(loaded)) {
                        classes.add(loaded);
                    }
                } catch (final NoClassDefFoundError ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ImmutableList.copyOf(classes);
}

private List<Class<?>> findClassesInSourceRoot(
        @NonNull final ClassLoader classLoader,
        @NonNull final File sourceRoot,
        @NonNull final Predicate<Class<?>> predicate
) {
    File[] files = sourceRoot.listFiles();

    if (files == null) return new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> classNames = getClassNames("", sourceRoot, sourceRoot);
    try {
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{sourceRoot.toURI().toURL()}, classLoader);

        for (String className : classNames) {
            try {
                Class<?> aClass = loader.loadClass(className);
                if (predicate.test(aClass)) {
                    classes.add(aClass);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return classes;
}

private List<String> getClassNames(String basePath, File sourceRoot, File file) {

    ArrayList<String> classNames = new ArrayList<>();
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
        classNames.add(basePath + file.getName().replace(".class", ""));
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File subFile : files) {
                classNames.addAll(getClassNames(file.equals(sourceRoot) ? "" : basePath + file.getName() + ".", sourceRoot, subFile));
            }
        }
    }

    return classNames;
}
```

}

My methods i use:

```
    private void loadModes() {

    File file = new File("plugins/MyPlugin/TheFolderWhereTheAddonsAreIn");

    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    addFromDir(file);
    addFromDir(new File("plugins")); //to check the plugins folder if there is an addon as a plugin

    for(Class<? extends SpectateMode> spectateMode : listedSpectateModes) {
        if(spectateMode != null) {
            //spectateMode.onEnable(); //not possible to enter
            Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.CONFIG, spectateMode.getName() + " loaded");
        }
    }

}

private void addFromDir(File dir) {
    SPClassLoader loader = new SPClassLoader();

    Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(dir.listFiles())).forEach(jar -> {
        if(jar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
            if(!loader.findClasses(instance.getClassLoader(), jar, SpectateMode.class).isEmpty()) {
                listedSpectateModes.addAll(loader.findClasses(instance.getClassLoader(), jar, SpectateMode.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

SpectateMode class:

```
public abstract class SpectateMode {

/**
 * Do something when the SpectateMode get registered
 * For example registering an EventListener
 */
public abstract void onEnable();

/**
 * Returns the name of the SpectateMode
 *
 * @return the name of the SpectateMode
 */
public abstract String getName();

/**
 * Gets executed every Tick when a player has equipped this mode
 */
public abstract void execute(Spectator spectator);
}
```

Looking forward for a positive answer.

Greets.

Comment: I think you’ll find that [java.util.ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) already does all of this work for you.

Comment: this got me confused ...  "Now my ClassLoader is giving me back a list with Class<? extends MyClass>, but I need them to be Class<?> to execute the methods of this class" ... you can't call any methods from Class<?>, you have to get constructor and instance it... only then you can call it's methods.